# Entity framework not getting data from the repository of inherited object

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I am relatively new to EF and I am still in learning process. I have a repository created from which I get the data from the database.

I have the following structure of classes:

```
public class Foo1 : CQA, IScorable
{
    private double score;

    public double Score
    {
        get
        {
            return score;
        }
        set
        {
            var t = Question; // this is where Question is always null
            score = value;
        }
    }

    protected Foo1() { }

    public Foo1(CQ q, QO co) : base(question, new List<AO>())
    {

    }
}

public class CQA : Answer
{
    public virtual IList<AO> AO { get; set; }

    protected CQA() { }

    public CQA(Question question, IList<AO> ao) : base(question)
    {
        AO = ao;
    }
}

public class Answer : IEntity<int>
{
    public virtual Question Question { get; set; } // This is null

    public int Id { get; set; }

    protected Answer() { }

    public Answer(Question question)
    {
        Question = question;
    }
}
```

Mapped table is:

```
public class AnswerMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Answer>
{
    public AnswerMap()
    {
        ToTable(nameof(Answer));
        HasRequired(x => x.Question);
    }
}
```

This is the class that I get from the repo:

```
    public abstract class Test : IEntity<int>
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual IList<Answer> Answers { get; set; }

    protected Test()
    {
        Answers = new List<Answer>();
    }

    public virtual Test AddAnswer(Answer answer)
    {
        var found = Answers.FirstOrDefault(l => l.Question.Id == answer.Question.Id);

        if (found != null)
        {
            var index = Answers.IndexOf(found);
            Answers.RemoveAt(index);
            Answers.Insert(index, answer);
        }
        else
        {
            Answers.Add(answer);
        }

        return this;
    }       
}
```

Answers are always null.

The strangest thing is I am always able to save the answer added for the fist time. Every other time I pull test from repo and AddAnswer method is called I get null in above mentioned places. Calling repo.SaveChanges method works only for the first time and data is inserted in database but after that errors occur.
Can anyone help what am I doing wrong?

The repository that I am using gets all the necessary data expect on lines above where I wrote that problem occurs.

EDIT 1:
Here is how I get the data from repo:

```
public interface IPSTRepository : IRepository<PTS>
    {
    }
```

And here is IRepository interface:

```
public interface IRepository<TObject> where TObject : class
{
    ICollection<TObject> GetAll();

    Task<ICollection<TObject>> GetAllAsync();

    TObject Get(int id);

    Task<TObject> GetAsync(int id);

    TObject Find(Expression<Func<TObject, bool>> match);

    Task<TObject> FindAsync(Expression<Func<TObject, bool>> match);

    ICollection<TObject> FindAll(Expression<Func<TObject, bool>> match);

    Task<ICollection<TObject>> FindAllAsync(Expression<Func<TObject, bool>> match);

    TObject Add(TObject t);

    TObject Update(TObject updated, int key);

    void Delete(TObject t);

    int Count();

    Task<int> CountAsync();

    int SaveChanges();

    Task<int> SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

Comment: How are you retrieving the Answer? I think you need to add answer.Include(x => x.Question);

Comment: I tried that also. It doesn't work. Then it break some EntityNotSureException.

Comment: Can you show your repository method that gets the data?

Comment: I added it. From the interface I use Get by id. It returns proper data with this Get method. But Answers are always null